# Using Xpath with XpathSelectElement in a Loop

Tags: c#, linq

```
for(int sp_range = int.Parse(myParser.GetKey("SP_Range")); sp_range < int.Parse(myParser.GetKey ("EP_Range")); sp_range++)
{
  cboPort.Items.Add(sp_range.ToString());

  main.XPathSelectElement("//ip_addresses").SetAttributeValue("id", sp_range.ToString());

  main.Save(xmlpath);
}
```

I am looping through a set number range, as I'm looping, I am incrementing an iterator I want the values of the iterator 1 through to 59 to be added as id value in my xml document it saves the id value but only adds to one Element named ip_addresses instead of adding to all the ip_addresses child elements its only adding it to one and the last count value of the iterator which is 59 so im using the correct Xpath that gets all child elements of the named element ip_addresses but its only access the first child element of the parent which Row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int sp_range = int.Parse(myParser.GetKey("SP_Range")); sp_range < int.Parse(myParser.GetKey("EP_Range")); sp_range++)
{
    cboPort.Items.Add(sp_range.ToString()); //Adds the load of values

    foreach (XElement xml in main.XPathSelectElements("/Row/ip_addresses"))
    {
        xml.SetAttributeValue("id", sp_range++);//You have to re-iterate for the set# Nodes
    }

}

main.Save(xmlpath);
```

This works great guys if you ever need to know how to do this I figured it over night